# how to return result as NULL if the SQL query return zero values in SQL

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have an sql query where I want to return the value as "NULL" if there is no result set after the query execution. I Have tried ISNULL property but, its generating an error,

[image]

my query is :

```
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT a.ReportDate, a.Scripcode, a.ISIN, a.Scripname, a.AccountNo, a.ClientLongName, a.GroupName, a.Event, a.TradedQty, a.UnreconQty, a.ExDateQty, a.RecDateQty, a.Diff, a.Rate, a.Ratio, a.TotalValue, a.Shares, a.StartDate, a.ExDate, a.RecordDate, a.PayDate, a.AgmDate, a.NSecName, a.NSecNo, a.Remark, b.GRUL_PROX_GRP_ID, b.GRUL_GROUPNO, b.CUSTOMERNO, b.GRUL_SHORTNAME, b.GRUP_SHORTCODE, b.CONF_TYP, b.SWIFT, b.FAX, b.COURIER, b.EMAIL, b.Account_Group, b.Excel_Word, b.Password, b.Sub_Account_Flag 
FROM       dbo.CRS_Entitlement_MasterDate AS a 
INNER JOIN dbo.CRS_Entitlement_EntitlementComn AS b 
ON         a.AccountNo = b.CUSTOMERNO
WHERE      (b.Account_Group = 'A') 
AND        (b.Excel_Word = 'E') 
AND        (b.SWIFT <> 'v') 
AND        (b.CONF_TYP <> 'N/A') 
AND        (b.FAX = 'v') 
OR         (b.Account_Group = 'A') 
AND        (b.Excel_Word = 'E') 
AND        (b.SWIFT <> 'v') 
AND        (b.CONF_TYP <> 'N/A') 
AND        (b.COURIER = 'v') 
OR         (b.Account_Group = 'A') 
AND        (b.Excel_Word = 'E') 
AND        (b.SWIFT <> 'v') 
AND        (b.CONF_TYP <> 'N/A') 
AND        (b.EMAIL = 'v')
ORDER BY   a.AccountNo), 0) AS Expr1
```

please help me to solve this ,Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Give us the script of the tables involved and sample data, and we will be happy to help!

Comment: ISNULL only works on a single column or expression, not an entire result set.  That's what is causing your  error.

Comment: @squillman also, `ISNULL` doesn't work the way op wants it to

Comment: What do you want to return when query returns data?

Comment: As an aside, please check the way you are using `AND` and `OR` in your `WHERE` conditions. I'm almost certain you got it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) like so:

```sql
-- returns NULL when it doesn't exist
SELECT  CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT   1 AS val
                           WHERE    1 = 2 ) THEN 1
             ELSE NULL
        END RESULT;

-- returns something else, in this case 1 when it does exist    
SELECT  CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT   1 AS val
                           WHERE    1 = 1 ) THEN 1
             ELSE NULL
        END RESULT;
```

> **EXISTS (Transact-SQL)**
>
> Specifies a subquery to test for the existence of rows.

A sample with data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #test ( id INT );

INSERT  INTO #test
        ( id )
VALUES  ( 1 ),
        ( 2 ),
        ( 3 );

-- returns data
IF ( EXISTS ( SELECT    *
              FROM      #test
              WHERE     id > 0 ) )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    #test
    WHERE   id > 0;
ELSE
    SELECT  NULL;

 -- returns NULL 
 IF ( EXISTS ( SELECT    *
              FROM      #test
              WHERE     id > 5 ) )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    #test
    WHERE   id > 5;
ELSE
    SELECT  NULL AS Result;


DROP TABLE #test;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't put multiple columns in inner query.for ex select top(100) percent a.ReportDate ---- will work